# Integrating windows active directory with apache tomcat to get username

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, integration

How can I integrate windows active directory with apache tomcat...so that clients username can be obtained when client tries to access the apache based application?
On each log in, username and password should be sent to apache tomcat server, which will return user role, depending upon which access rights will be given to user.
Thanks...

Comment: Hmm...you are asking the authentication to be done by ad. I presume you also want the roles to be decided based on some attributes in AD. In that case you are looking for authorization integration with AD. I am using Spring authentication and authorization to do that or you can use JAAS for that. I am not sure if Tomcat has that out of the box though.

Comment: Thanks Suresh...Can you just tell me how can I get current system username on tomcat?